# mapping my EC2 instance to the www.mydomain.com

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, godaddy, tomcat6, mapping

I am newbie to concepts like Cname, A record and all. I am running a EC2 instance with tomcat6. Now I need to map my java based application to www.mydomain.com.

I just went through few documents and FAQ's. I attached a elastic IP and mapped that Elastic IP to A address with host="www" and points to "elastic ip of my instance" now I am able to see the tomcat6 Root folder content. I need to map that directly my application, say I have my web application store in a folder called "myapp".

now if i type www.mydomain.com it should directly load the home of the my application "myapp"

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename you application as ROOT and everyhing should work.

For example, if your app is located at /tomcat/webapps/myapp, just rename it to /tomcat/webapps/ROOT

If there is already the default ROOT folder, just move it out of the way. You don't need the default root.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in the host [configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) for [apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk2/vhosthowto.html).

If you just have one app to do this with, it would be quicker to move the application from the folder myapp to the web host's document root. On a Debian EC2 instance this would be /var/www

Comment: I am not using apache I am using tomcat6, so do I need to change anything in the configuration files of tomcat6